# Launch images: Landscape left and landscape right for the iPad and iPad retina?

Tags: xcode, ios7

In regards to launch images in p.list file, how do I get landscape left and landscape right to appear as a 'Resource" for the iPad and iPad retina?
I only see 'Landscape Non-Retina'and 'Landscape Retina'
[image]

Comment: Why do you need different images for Landscape-Left and Landscape-Right? It is landscape anyway what is the difference for you?

Comment: Because, my app doesn't support landscape, so if they start the app in landscape left and I provided a landscape right image, then the launch image will not be correct.

Comment: If you don't support landscape then your app only shows portrait. Therefore you don't need and landscape launch images.

Comment: So I just leave the Landscape images with the following warning in the Resource: "No image with correct dimensions found"?

Comment: just remove those values from plist file. it'll be fine.

Comment: I don't see in my plist files. Maybe I'm looking for the wrong plist name. What should it be called in plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take that Xcode screen as a guide to remember the various image variants to include but lacks all the rotation possibilities.

iOS looks for an image to display as startup image based on it's name.
If it can not find a suitable file, iOS implements a fallback system looking for another image that can be eligible (always by name).
If none valid image is found simply displays a black screen.

The images files must be PNGs and included in the App Bundle.

The naming scheme is:

```
<basename><usage_specific_modifiers><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

- "Basename": can be "Default" or specified in app's Info.plist as value of key UILaunchImageFile
- "usage_specific_modifiers" PortraitUpsideDown, LandscapeLeft, etc.
- "scale_modifier": none or @2x (for retina)
- "device_modifier": -ipad or -iphone

You can find all the details here:
[iOS App Programming Guide - App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)